# python-dev install leads to "E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)"

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg

I have a problem with these deficiencies and I have tried everything but I still get this errors.

```
# apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib libpython2-dev libpython2-stdlib python python-minimal python2 python2-dev python2-minimal
Suggested packages:
  python-doc python2-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libpython2-dev libpython2-stdlib python2 python2-dev python2-minimal
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython-all-dev libpython-dev libpython-stdlib python python-minimal
5 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1960 not upgraded.
3 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/212 kB of archives.
After this operation, 311 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
(Reading database ... 373142 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python-minimal_2.7.15-3_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.prerm: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.prerm: find: not found
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-minimal_2.7.15-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 there is no script in the new version of the package - giving up
dpkg: considering deconfiguration of python-minimal, which would be broken by installation of python2-minimal ...
dpkg: yes, will deconfigure python-minimal (broken by python2-minimal)
Preparing to unpack .../python2-minimal_2.7.15-3_amd64.deb ...
De-configuring python-minimal (2.7.13-2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.prerm: 4: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.prerm: find: not found
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python2-minimal_2.7.15-3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess installed pre-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-minimal_2.7.15-3_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python2-minimal_2.7.15-3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)



root@LYNIX:~# dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-dev:
 python-dev depends on python (= 2.7.15-3); however:
  Version of python on system is 2.7.13-2.
 python-dev depends on libpython-dev (= 2.7.15-3); however:
  Version of libpython-dev:amd64 on system is 2.7.13-2.
 python-dev depends on python2-dev (= 2.7.15-3); however:
  Package python2-dev is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package python-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-all-dev:
 python-all-dev depends on python (= 2.7.15-3); however:
  Version of python on system is 2.7.13-2.
 python-all-dev depends on libpython-all-dev (= 2.7.15-3); however:
  Version of libpython-all-dev:amd64 on system is 2.7.13-2.
 python-all-dev depends on python-dev (= 2.7.15-3); however:
  Package python-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-all-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-all:
 python-all depends on python (= 2.7.15-3); however:
  Version of python on system is 2.7.13-2.

dpkg: error processing package python-all (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-dev
 python-all-dev
 python-all
```

Has anyone an idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Your system might be hosed if core utilities like find are missing. Could you please try to reinstall it with `sudo apt-get install -f --reinstall ubuntu-minimal coreutils findutils`? Apt will then reinstall the corrupted package and then try to fix the other package management issues. Please report back with the results. If my suggestion fails please also include the output of `echo "$PATH"` and `which -a find`. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, here's what I did:

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ less /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.prerm
#! /bin/sh
set -e

find /usr/share/python/ -name '*.py[oc]' -delete

walt@bat:~(0)$ type -a find
find is /usr/bin/find
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

What this means is that `/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-minimal.prerm` tries to use the `find` utility by looking in your `$PATH`. It's not there.

But, `find` is `/usr/bin/find`, so `/usr/bin` is NOT in your `$PATH`.

Check your startup files (`~/.bashrc`, read `man bash`, the "INVOCATION" section) for where you set `PATH=`.

Here's part of a `$PATH` that will work for `root`:

```
export PATH=/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin
```

That should get you going, but won't have all your customizations.

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, and root's `PATH` shouldn't include `local` or `games` directories. I changed it.